# What's the exact input size in MultiHead-Attention of BERT?

Tags: bert-language-model, transformer-model, attention-model, multihead-attention

I just recently learned [BERT](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805).

Some tutorials show that after embedding a sentence, a matrix **X of [seq_len, 768]** will be formed, and **X will be sent to MultiHead_Attention**, that is, multiple Self-Attentions.

But in [fasterTransformer](https://github.com/NVIDIA/FasterTransformer), why is the input [seq_len, head_num, size_per_head]? **It seems that it divides the matrix X equally according to the number of heads** and sends it to each head, instead of the complete matrix X.

**So what is the real input?**